# display longer product name in 2 lines in magento

Tags: css, magento

Under a product I have a longer product name, which needs to be displayed on 2 lines instead of 1.

How can I display a long productname on 2 lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it using the applying CSS to the `.best-sell-product` class:

```css
.best-sell-product {
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

You can change the width as per requirement.
Hope it will work.